# How to set simple PAGINATION in broadleaf opensource?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pagination, thymeleaf

The Following code is working fine with pagination. But while trying to load another list on the session attribute "pagedProductList" without reload the page, I am getting error...

Product Controller Code :

```
String page = request.getParameter("page");
    PagedListHolder<Product> products = new PagedListHolder<Product>();
     if ("previous".equals(page)) { 
         products = (PagedListHolder<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("pagedProductList"); 
         products.previousPage(); 
     } else if ("next".equals(page)) { 
         products = (PagedListHolder<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("pagedProductList"); 
         products.nextPage(); 
     } else { 
         products = new PagedListHolder<Product>(allValidProducts); 
         products.setPageSize(10); 
         request.getSession().setAttribute("pagedProductList", products); 
     }
```

Html :

```
<tbody id="productList" >
            <tr th:each="product : ${products.pageList}">
                <td style="min-width:300px;"> <a th:href="@{editProduct/(productId=${product.id})}" th:text="${product.name}">name</a> </td>
                <td style="width:400px;" th:text="${product.url}">URL</td>
                <td style="width:200px;" th:text="${product.id}">ID</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"> <hr/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"> 
                    <a th:if="${!products.firstPage}" th:href="@{/virtualadmin/listProducts(keyword=${param.keyword}, page='previous')}">Previous</a> 
                        <span th:text="${products.page + 1}">1</span> 
                    <a th:if="${!products.lastPage}" th:href="@{/virtualadmin/listProducts(keyword=${param.keyword}, page='next')}">Next</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what version of broadleaf are you using? if you use demo project with broadleaf 3.1.6-GA, pagination should be out of the box implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spring's PagedListHolder utility to help pagination in the Controller like that:

```
    String page = request.getParameter("page"); 
    PagedListHolder<Product> products; 
    if ("previous".equals(page)) { 
        products = (PagedListHolder<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("pagedProductList"); 
        products.previousPage(); 
    } else if ("next".equals(page)) { 
        products = (PagedListHolder<Product>) request.getSession().getAttribute("pagedProductList"); 
        products.nextPage(); 
    } else { 
        products = new PagedListHolder<Product>(productDAO.searchByKeyword(keyword)); 
        products.setPageSize(10); 
        request.getSession().setAttribute("pagedProductList", products); 
    } 
    model.addAttribute("products", products);
```

and in the template you can browse results like that:

```
   <div th:each="product : ${products.pageList}">
         ... 
   </div>
```

and add page navigation like that:

```
   < a th:if="${!products.firstPage}" 
            th:href="@{/search.html(keyword=${param.keyword}, page='previous')}">Previous< /a> 
   < span th:text="${products.page + 1}">1 / 10< /span> 
   < a th:if="${!products.lastPage}" 
            th:href="@{/search.html(keyword=${param.keyword}, page='next')}">Next< /a>
```